# Specifying runtime dependency in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-tika

I am attempting to run a simple Spark app which uses Apache Tika to extract metadata.  I have created a shaded jar with Maven and the app runs fine, but the Tika parsers are not being used at runtime.  The app code is below:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
if (args.length == 0 || args[0] == null) {
    return;
}
JavaPairRDD<String,PortableDataStream> files = sc.binaryFiles(args[0]);
List<Map<String,String>> results = files.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,PortableDataStream>, Map<String,String>>() {

    public Map<String,String> call(Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream> stringPortableDataStreamTuple2) throws Exception {
        DataInputStream des = stringPortableDataStreamTuple2._2.open();
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
        String detected = tika.detect(des);
        Map<String,String> metadata = new HashMap();
        metadata.put("Type", detected);
        Metadata tikaMetadata = new Metadata();
        parser.parse(des, handler, tikaMetadata, new ParseContext());
        String[] names = tikaMetadata.names();
        for (String name : names) {
            metadata.put(name, tikaMetadata.get(name));
        }
        return metadata;
    }
}).collect();
for (Map<String,String> o : results) {
    for (String key : o.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " : " + o.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
sc.stop();
```

The output is always something like:

```
Type : image/jpeg
X-Parsed-By : org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser
Content-Type : application/octet-stream
```

Which indicates the Tika parsers are not being used.  According to the docs, I can configure runtime dependencies using the spark.driver.extraClassPath property, so I modified my $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template file to have:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /path/to/tika/jar/tika-app-1.13.jar
```

It is still not working, can anyone help me understand why?  Alternatively, is there a better way to specify runtime dependencies?  I'm currently running the app through spark-submit in local mode only, using Spark 1.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add dependency jars using *`--jars`* while submitting application,

for example,

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  --jars /path/to/tika/jar/tika-app-1.13.jar \
  /path/to/examples.jar
```

[Ways of adding jars for execution](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)

Comment: In addition to above, In cluster deploy-mode, make sure that the jars are globally visible across all nodes like(s3:// or hdfs://) or copy the jars in all worker node in the same path.

Comment: Not really required unless the jars are huge and you want to avoid network traffic.

Comment: Required in case of standalone mode. https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201512.mbox/%3C86B9571C-E894-4B53-AFB2-285A507A4AE2@danielvaldivia.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

The code which is in the `map` function of an RDD is executed on an executor, not the driver. Since you are using `Tika` in the `map`, you need to have the neccessary jars copied to each executors

You could do that by:

- Prefered solution , As mentiioned in the answer of #WoodChopper, by using `--jars`
- or if you prefer, adding to spak-defaults.conf the following line:
  `spark.executor.extraClassPath /path/to/tika/jar/tika-app-1.13.jar`